# www.Example.com works but not root (Example.com)

Tags: apache

I am using Apache2 with UBUNTU14 LTS, all "standard" server.

The problem is simple, **when using `http://www.example.com` it works fine, but when using `http://example.com` it doesn't, it goes to the wrong index.**

---

### Describing details

I have folders at `ls /var/www/`

```
  example.com  example2.example  html              
  wiki.example.com  wp.example2.example
```

Each with different and good index.htm working with `http://www.example.com` (goes to `/var/www/example.com`) or `http://wiki.example.com`, etc. But the index of `http://example.com` goes to `/var/www/html/index.htm`, not to `/var/www/example.com` (!).

---

At `/etc/apache2/sites-available/example.com.conf` we have,

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin mymail@ggmail.com
        ServerName example.com
        ServerAlias www.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName wiki.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/wiki.example.com
</VirtualHost>
```

---

EDIT (notes)

We are using a workaround — and please ignore the "real world" examples in the comments, it is not valid as real testing —, an ugly piece of PHP code (*not a solution*) in the `/var/www/html/index.php` of the root (no subdomain), to redirect to www subdomain,

```
  if ( preg_match(  // if HTTP from other domain, redirects 
         '/(mydomain1|mydomain2|mydomain3)/',
         strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']),
         $m
      ) ) switch($m[1]) {
    case 'mydomain1':
        header("Location: https://www.example.com"); die('');
    case 'mydomain2':
        header("Location: https://www.example2.example"); die('');
    case '...':
        header("Location: https://www...."); die('');
    }
```

---

EDIT

As @covener comment suggest,  `apachectl -S`, results in

```
VirtualHost configuration:
*:80                   is a NameVirtualHost
         default server localhost (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:1)
         port 80 namevhost localhost (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:1)
         port 80 namevhost atarica.com.br (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/atarica.com.br.conf:1)
                 alias www.atarica.com.br
         port 80 namevhost wiki.atarica.com.br (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/atarica.com.br.conf:13)
         port 80 namevhost atarica.com.br (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/fabrincantes.com.conf:1)
                 alias www.fabrincantes.com
         port 80 namevhost yellowtown.org (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/yellowtown.org.conf:1)
                 alias www.yellowtown.org
         port 80 namevhost wiki.yellowtown.org (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/yellowtown.org.conf:35)
ServerRoot: "/etc/apache2"
Main DocumentRoot: "/var/www"
Main ErrorLog: "/var/log/apache2/error.log"
Mutex default: dir="/var/lock/apache2" mechanism=fcntl 
Mutex mpm-accept: using_defaults
Mutex watchdog-callback: using_defaults
PidFile: "/var/run/apache2/apache2.pid"
Define: DUMP_VHOSTS
Define: DUMP_RUN_CFG
User: name="www-data" id=33 not_used
Group: name="www-data" id=33 not_used
```

Comment: If you need to check in real world, see [http://www.fabrincantes.com](http://www.fabrincantes.com) (that is with good index), and [http://fabrincantes.com](http://fabrincantes.com) that I need with *same* index.htm, but goes to the `/var/www/html/index.htm`

Comment: Best to use one or the other, not both. I don't think there is a *large* penalty for having both, the best would be use the www version and redirect non-www versions to it.

Comment: Hi @John, thanks clues... Yes, it is the goal (!) I need *non-www=www*,  ... But why is not working?? There are a `ServerAlias` and a `ServerName`, they are correct...

Comment: Also I'd use abc or xyz, not xxx as placeholder...because you know, that one is a bit open to interpretation. :-)

Comment: See the "real world" commented above with no placeholder ;-)

Comment: Hi @Jonh, I edited, please ignore "real world example" because it changed, and now have the described workaround. See edited question text.

Comment: You're showing a file in sites-available/ -- there's no indication it's loaded in your configuration.  Try apachectl -S

Comment: Hi @covener I edit adding the `apachectl -S` report

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    Redirect permanent / http://www.example.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

Then you just need to create another  section with **ServerName www.example.com** for your real server configuration.

Also, wouldn't CNAME's records work has an alternative to this? (I'm not sure)

Comment: It  is also a workaround with same (wrong) behaviour tham my PHP's workaround. The request http://example.com/abc?xyz=1 will be lost... Can you fix your solution?

Comment: @PeterKrauss — The Redirect directive should preserve everything after the section of path in the redirect.

Comment: Thanks @Quentin , you correct. Thanks Richasantos, good clue... The debug process was started by  the comment of covener (to try `apachectl -S`), them the error is showed (see my edit and my answer). So I not give to Richasantos  the bounty, but I take the second votes, so  a half of the bounty.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry all, that was my "human error", as blind spot when reading `file.conf` scripts, and a general blindness here after my edit showing `apachectl -S` results, the error is there (! see `fabrincantes.com` lines), a wrong name "AAA" on the "BBB" configuration:

```
     port 80 namevhost AAA (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/BBB.conf:1)
             alias BBB
```

so I fixed with simple name correction on my `BBB.conf`, that has an `ServerName AAA` instead "BBB",

```
   <VirtualHost *:80>
    ...
    ServerName BBB
    ...
   </VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score -1):

You would require to edit your **/etc/hosts** file so it points to correct links.

For example,  configuration on my localhost would be

127.0.1.1 example.com www.example.com